# Magnolia CMS create page/component template programmatically

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I would like to keep all my settings, templates etc. in the repository. So it would be nice, to have it in separate files.

Is is possible to create magnolia template programmatically using the Standard Templating Kit? If yes, where can I find any useful information about that? I have searched in the magnolia documentation, but I didn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on one hand you say you want to create your templates programatically, on the other you say you want to keep all in repo, so which is it? If you want to programatically create some configuration in the repo, yes it is possible. But "how" depends on "when" you actually want to create those definitions.

Perhaps simplest is to use groovy console or groovy script to do so. In order to have Magnolia recognize your template definitions, you need to place them in `/modules/<yourmodulename>/templates/<pages|components>/<pathtoyourtemplate>` and make sure you give each template definition you create app properties it needs. You should also make sure that node type of those templates is `mgnl:contentNode` while node type of any folders you create above is `mgnl:content`.

As for the template scripts you need to place those in `templates` workspace, not sure of the node type for that one, but you can find out quickly by exporting one that is already there. For all other resources you want, load them in the `resources` workspace.

Last but not least, if you want all to be in the repo, you can use groovy classes for your models. Just when creating template definition specify fully qualified name for `modelClass` property that points to a groovy class in groovy workspace instead of pointing to java class.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: I would like to keep my template's definitions(.java) in repository. I know i can do that using blossom and spring. But is it the only way to define templates and controllers in .java? Documentation says that if I want to create template using stk etc. I have to make .jsp and set template definition(set some nodes properties). All what I would like to do is create page,ares and component templates definition in java instead of setting it manually in magnolia admincentral.

Comment: Nope. If you use blossom, your template definitions are just annotations in your java code. But that java code doesn't live in the repository. Magnolia will resolve it at runtime from the class path.

Comment: If you want to be able to edit template definitions at runtime, you have to indeed create them in the repository (as opposed to using annotations in Spring controllers). As for the template scripts themselves, if you choose jsp, those again have to live in the file system of the webapp (because of jsp spec and what jsp compiler expects). If you want to store template scripts in the repo, you need to write those scripts in freemarker.

Comment: And template scripts you need whether or not you store configuration in repo or use Blossom/SpringMVC ... either way you need to specify them as either templateScript property or as view in your Spring controller.

Comment: My bad sorry! I didn't specify what i mean by "repository". By repository I mean version control repo like github not magnolia repository. So actually I'm looking for something like Blossom, so I would be able to define my templates and other resources in Java, using annotation or anything else. Blossom works fine but I would like to look on other options if they exists.

Comment: Ah that. Now it's clear :D   You can always export the configuration you make in repo and put it in your module in /src/main/resources/mgnl-bootstrap/yourmodule/ folder and have Magnolia to bootstrap it on installation of the module . Or you need to wait month or two until Magnolia 5.4 is released. In 5.4 is new feature that allows you to keep configuration in yaml files in the filesystem so you can have those easily in your version control system too.

Comment: Export configuration is an option but it would be nice to have possibility to edit it. Exported xml's are hard to read and edit so it's good to hear about yaml feature. Anyway Blossom works fine so let's stay with it and wait for another great feature. Thx for your time!